# Inline "display: none;" is being automatically added when page is rendered - where might I look for the cause?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a form element (a checkbox) that I have added to a UI form.  When the page is rendered, the Chrome F12 debugger shows that `display: none;` has been added as a style; i.e.,

```
element.style {
   display: none;
}
```

... is seen in the Styles pane of the Chrome debugger for the `<input>` element on my form.  (In fact, it is not even possible for me to uncheck this style in the Styles pane of the Chrome debugger - the checkmark stays frozen in place - even though I can easily uncheck other style entries.)

Here is (what I think is) the relevant HTML:

```
...
<div class="box">
    ...
    <form id="edit-dish" action="..." method="post">
        <div class="form">
            ...
            <p>
                <input  id="one-label-per-serving"
                        name="ingredient[one_label_per_serving]"
                        type="checkbox"
                        autocomplete="off"
                        class="checkbox checkbox-inline validate[required]"
                        <?php if ( Arr::get($dish, 'one_label_per_serving', FALSE) ): ?>
                            checked="checked"
                        <?php endif; ?> />
                <span class="checkbox-label">One label per serving</span>
            </p>
            ...
        </div>
        ...
    </form>
...
</div>
...
```

The dots represent things I've left off that I hope & think are not relevant.

The `<span>` element is displayed just fine.  But, the `<input>` checkbox has the `display: none;` added to its inline style immediately upon page load.

There is also a sidebar, header, and footer being automatically included by a template.

I have some confidence that one of the included Javascript libraries is causing the problem.  Here are the loaded Javascript libraries (according to Chrome's debugger):

```
jquery.min.js
jquery-ui.min.js
jquery.tmpl.min.js
fileuploader.js
jquery.form.js
jquery.reveal.js
jquery.validationEngine-en.js
jquery.validationEngine.js
jquery.wysiwyg.js
master.v2.js // <-- this is the application's custom script
```

The `master.v2.js` is the application's custom script.  Searching inside it, I find nowhere that it is setting `display: none;` for this element.

Does anyone have any suggestions about either what Javascript file might be setting `display: none;`, or how to go about debugging this?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried removing different classes to see if that leads to some clues?

Comment: You probably won't find a script explicitly setting `display:none;`, most likely this is the result of jQuery's `hide()`

Comment: @AndrewBarber Yes.  I have been playing around with that, and other things; I attempted different things for about an hour before posting this question.  I am continuing to debug to try to determine what is happening.

Comment: What's really strange is that the `display: none;` property is uncheckable. Have you tested that in another browse? It could possibly be something like a misfunction of some extension.

Comment: You could add a breakpoint for `Attributes Modifications` in Dev Tool and then work your way to the source from there.

Comment: can you show us an screenshot of the styles on the element using developer tools in chrome?

Comment: @koala_dev The culprit was a `toggle()` function inside the application's Javascript file.  The lesson is to search for `toggle` as well as `hide` and `display: none;`.

Comment: I am answering my own question in order to possibly help others in the future who encounter a similar issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The culprit was a call to `toggle()` that was matching the element in question inside the application's custom Javascript file.

As @koala_dev noted in a comment, it is important to search for `hide()` when searching for potential locations where `display: none;` might be added.  But, it is also important to search for `toggle()`.

I am answering my own question in case others in the future run into this issue.

Comment: ok, but what about the property uncheckability? That's really strange. I think that `hide()` and `toggle()` shouldn't make that uncheckable.

Comment: @falsarella Agreed.  I wish I didn't have a deadline or else I'd look into it!

Comment: @GaryStorey Users are not allowed to mark their own answers as accepted for 2 days (otherwise, I would have).

Answer (score 2):

I had this happening to me as well and it was caused by Adblocking extensions in Google Chrome.

Comment: Same in Firefox. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In my case the culprit was the the use of fadeIn(100).fadeOut(100). I actually wanted to give a blinking animation on a click. I only needed to use

$("#id").fadeIn(100).fadeOut(100); // that's when the problem occurred.

Solution:

$("#id").fadeIn(100).fadeOut(100).fadeIn(100);

Didn't actually need the second fadeIn(100) though.
But it solved my problem. Still confused how it could solve the issue.